# How to control link, form placement on header image?

Tags: css, html

I really like how this site has a login link and search box on the banner image. But I don't understand how they control the placement so that those items end up precisely in the place where they show up. ANy advice or link to a tutorial to do something similar would be great!

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Can you explain more about placement?

Comment: Open developer tools, inspect the elements?!

Comment: I ended up using Firebug and that gave me great insight. But I am using a gantry template in joomla and its nested divs make it very unclear which divs I would have to edit to get desired positioning.